# Paste flip animation does not give the expected results

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine, nla-editor, dopesheet, makehuman

I am doing a walk cycle using an imported .mhx file. To do the walk cycle, I animate the legs and hand for the first frame then I paste the inverse in the frame 21 (in my case).
In the first scenario: I imported the model then I click in the red button and I made the walk cycle without problem (see fig 1 and 2)
[image: fig1]
[image: fig2]
In the second case: I moved the model in an other place without insert any key frames (I turn off the button red)
[image: fig3]
[image: fig4]
after that I turn on the red button and I apply the same process but I remark that the person flip relative to the x-axis. I did not understand why I did not get the same results? (because I did not insert any key frame when I moved the person!!!)
[image: fig5]

Comment: It is incomprehensible problem! I think that is related to makehuman